# Angular and not angular forms within the same page

Tags: angularjs

I have two forms on a single page. One form I am adding/deleting which is working fine. Now in the second form (which I don't want to do anything through angular)

But I am not able to submit this(second form). Both the forms are inside my app. Anybody have any idea please share.

I can see when I refresh the page "ng-pristine ng-valid" classes are added in my second form.

This is my first form

```
    <div class="address address-form"  ng-hide="!isEdit">
      <form class="edit-address-form"  ng-submit="updateAddress(currentAddress.aid);">
        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="sr-only" for="first_name">First name </label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" value="testing" name="first_name" value="{{currentAddress.first_name}}" placeholder="First name"  required ng-model="currentAddress.first_name">


        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="sr-only" for="last_name">Last name</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name"  name="last_name" placeholder="Last name" ng-model="currentAddress.last_name" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="sr-only" for="phone">Phone/mobile</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone"  ng-model="currentAddress.phone">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="sr-only" for="street">Street address</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="street" name="street" placeholder="Street address"  ng-model="currentAddress.street">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="sr-only" for="city">City</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" placeholder="City" ng-model="currentAddress.city" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="sr-only" for="postal_code">Postal code</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="postal_code" name="postal_code" placeholder="Postal code" ng-model="currentAddress.postal_code" >
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="sr-only" for="country">Country</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="country" name="country" placeholder="Country"  autofocus ng-model="currentAddress.country">
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
           <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" ng-show="errorMsg">{{errorMsg}}</div>
           <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" ng-show="successMsg">{{successMsg}}</div>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="button-update-address" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'></i> Updating address...">Update address</button>


        </div>
     </form>

</div>
```

This one second form

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Payment Summary</h3>
 </div>
  <div class=" ">
<form id="confirm-order" name="confirm_order" method="POST" action="">
<div class="form-group">
  <?php 
     if($con->returned_rows):
         $row = $con->fetch_assoc();

    ?>      
     <table class="table">  
       <tr>
          <td> Sub total </td>
          <td><?php   print $row['subtotal']   ;?><input type="hidden" name="subtotal" value="<?php   print $row['subtotal']   ;?>"/></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Total items </td>
         <td><?php   print $row['total_qty']   ;?></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Shipping</td>
         <td><?php   //print $row['total_qty']   ;?></td>
       </tr>
    </table>

<?php  endif; ?>
   </div>

  <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" name="confirm" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"  value="Confirm order"/>
 </div>
    </form>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

angular has directive named `form`, because of which it considers your form directive in angular-scope.

if you want this directive to be out of angular-scope, use ngNonBindable

```
 <form ng-non-bindable>
        .....
 </form>
```